# How to consume artifacts in AzureDevops build pipeline from one job to another job

Tags: azure-devops

I have created a build pipeline, where

in Job1:  I create a specific file in python container 
in Job2:  I would like to use that file for my next process to consume in Docker Container

To achieve this, I have created artifact called `configCreate` for Job1 and in job2 I was trying to download the artifact created above in `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)`. But when I tried to access the file I still see the file from source not the file from Job1. How can I access the artifact from Job1 artifact to Job2 ? [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)

So,

```
 stages:
    - stage: Build
      displayName: BUILD NON MASTER BRANCH
      condition: and(succeeded(), ne(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master'))

      variables:
      - group: Common_DEV

      jobs:
      - job: buildConfig
        displayName: 'Create Properties file.'
        container: python3
        pool: rhel

        steps:
          - bash: echo "Hello World!!! - $(Build.SourceBranch)"
            displayName: "Started building for $(Build.SourceBranch)"
          - bash: |
              echo PythonV3
              python3 -m venv venv
              source venv/bin/activate
              python --version
              pip3 install -r $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/requirements.txt
              python3 injectConfigProperties.py
              echo "Finish creating the Properties."
              deactivate
              rm -r venv/
              cat $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/properties/config.properties
            displayName: Build Config file 
        - task: CopyFiles@2
            inputs:
              contents: |
                $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
              targetFolder: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
          - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
            inputs:
              pathtoPublish: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
              artifactName: configCreate

        - job: Job2
            displayName: 'JOb2'
            container: docker
            pool: rhel

            dependsOn:
            - buildConfig
            condition: succeeded()

            steps:
              - task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@0
                displayName: 'Download Build Artifacts from buildConfig.'
                inputs:
                  artifactName: configCreate
                  downloadPath: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)

         - bash: |
                  cat $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/properties/config.properties
                  ls -ltr $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/pipelines/
                displayName: 'Build Docker Image'
```

Answer (score 0):

in job2 to access the artifact is `cat $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/artifactName/properties/config.properties`

I missed artifact Name to access the artifact. Now it's fixed.